# How to delete a Registry key?

Tags: c#, registry

I want to run this DOS command in C#, without executing a DOS command.

```
REG DELETE HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\WindowsApplication1\Status /f
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach. Note that you have to pass true to OpenSubKey in order to get Write permission.

```
var hklm = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine;
var subkey = hklm.OpenSubKey("Software\\Wow6432Node\\WindowsApplication1", true);
subkey.DeleteSubKey("Status");
```

Answer (score 1):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h3yfwzfx.aspx

```
 Registry.CurrentUser.DeleteSubKeyTree("Test9999");
```

best tutorial for your question

http://www.jagjot.com/2013/02/read-write-delete-windows-registry-c/

Comment: What should i give for "test9999" ?
WindowsApplication1 or Status Or WindowsApplication1\\Status ???

Comment: in link below full answer for your question

`Software\\Wow6432Node\\WindowsApplication1`

Answer (score 1):

Or if you are looking to run the DOS command from C# then you could use

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd.exe", "REG DELETE HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\WindowsApplication1\Status /f")
```

Comment: This was not worked for me. Just opening command prompt as usual & passing that line of code successfully. But the key is not deleted.